# See all Firebase notifications sent via HTTP protocol

Tags: http, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications, firebase-console

I can see a list of the notifications sent via the Firebase console.  However, if I send a notification via the HTTP protocol (https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send) it is not in the list.  Where can I see the complete list of sent notifications?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no list of messages sent via the APIs. There are aggregates available in the Play Developer Console if your app is an Android app published via Play Store but this does not include a list, just counts.